# not updating the notifications in android

Tags: android, notifications

i ma making an app an i want to show the notifications first time it runs good but the second time it is not updating the list in the notifications.

```
public class StatusBar extends Activity {
NotificationManager mn;
static int uniqueId = 1394885;
static ArrayList<String> arrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    arrayList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("nameOfFilesCopied");
    mn = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mn.cancel(uniqueId);

    ahoo();

}

private void ahoo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent("helpsettings.ListOfFilesCopied");
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("nameOfFilesCopied", arrayList);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    String body = "List of files that are copied by the connected person";
    String title = "List Of Files Copied";
    // need to craate a notification i.e what the time is
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, body,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    // add what details we want to our notification
    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi);
    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    mn.notify(uniqueId, n);
    finish();

}
```

}
on second time when i put the arrayList and through pending intent i invoke the below class
the pending intent send the previous list not the one that is on the second itme
    public class ListOfFilesCopied extends ListActivity {

```
ArrayList<String> list;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    list = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("nameOfFilesCopied");
    adapter = new MyAdapters(this, R.layout.ahoo, list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onBackPressed()
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    list.clear();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void ahoo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent("helpsettings.ListOfFilesCopied");
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("nameOfFilesCopied", arrayList);


    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    String body = "List of files that are copied by the connected person";
    String title = "List Of Files Copied";
    // need to craate a notification i.e what the time is
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, body,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    // add what details we want to our notification
    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi);
    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    mn.notify(uniqueId, n);
    finish();

}
```

Comment: PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Answer (score 0):

this is my code for notification update...works like a charm...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DrillListViewActivity.this, DrillListViewActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
/*
 * TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder
 * .create(DrillListViewActivity.this);
 * 
 * stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
 */
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
DrillListViewActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    noti = new Notification.Builder(
    DrillListViewActivity.this)
    .setContentTitle(drill.getName())
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setContentText(
        "Rest time: " + drill.getTimeMin()
        + ":" + drill.getTimeSec()
        + "    Reps: "
        + drill.getReps()
        + "     Sets: "
        + drill.getNumberOfSets())
    .setSubText(" Notes:" + drill.getNotes())
    .getNotification();
} else {
    noti = new Notification.Builder(
    DrillListViewActivity.this)
    .setContentTitle(drill.getName())
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setContentText(
    LongString)  
    .getNotification();
}

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Hide the notification after its selected
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

hope it helps you out
you can put it in rowclick so that it'll update each time you choose a row...